# sending mail using sendmail with attachment in Tcl

Tags: tcl, sendmail

Hi I am trying to send mail using `sendmail` in Tcl with attachment.

This is my code as follows,

```
set mail_ids "dinesh@mydomain.com"



set msg {From: dinesh}
set timestamp [ clock format [clock seconds] -format {%d-%m-%Y-at-%HH-%MM-%Ss} ]
append msg \n "To:$mail_ids"

append msg \n "Subject: $subject"
append msg \n "Hi,\nPlease find the report generated on $timestamp.\n"
append msg \n "\nAuto-generated email via script\n"
append msg  [ exec cat db.config | uuencode db.config ]
#append msg $report

puts "Sending mail now ..... "


exec /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t << $msg


puts "Mail sent."
```

While running this, I am getting the following error

```
wrong # args: should be "exec handle cmd"
    while executing
"exec cat db.config | uuencode db.config "
    invoked from within
"append msg  [ exec cat db.config | uuencode db.config ]"
    (file "./my_script" line 478)
```

I am having the file 'db.config' in the current directory where the script is running.

What mistake i am making here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's bizarre; you're using correct Tcl syntax there. I'm guessing that something has overwritten the `exec` command in that interpreter with a non-standard implementation. (I do remember creating an image called `open` long ago and wondering why my file accesses started failing… ☺)

Comment: What can we do here to overcome this problem Donald ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in my code. I had one proc named 'exec' with 2 arguments and I found that the code

```
exec /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t << $msg
```

is calling out the user-defined 'exec' proc, not the tcl's `exec`, which is why it is throwing error as `wrong # args: should be "exec handle cmd"`.

Mr.Donal is correct. I did the same mistake as yours. Thanks Donal. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
append msg  [ exec cat db.config | uuencode db.config ]
```

With:

```
append msg  [ exec uuencode db.config db.config ]
```